# How to provide path to assets within a react project hosted on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firebase

I created a react app, using `npx create-react-app my-app`. After I ran `npm run build` I deployed it on firebase using `firebase deploy`. Unfortunately, it did not display anything on the hosting link.  After that, I rewrote all file paths such as:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.493343f3.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="./css/main.493343f3.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After this, the project did work (when it was hosted) except the images.

I went to the `main.17a5dc8e.chunk.js` file and rewrote all file paths:

```
"static/media/placeholder.3a8380d3.jpg"
```

to

```
"./media/placeholder.3a8380d3.jpg"
```

But still nothing.
What did I mess up?
How should I fix it?

Comment: What error message appears when you try to visit the site?

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: When the project was working without images. There would have been errors in the webpage console stating the problem with loading them. That would give a good indication to errors in the code

Comment: Just a warming to remove aces SDK-s

Comment: Do you have a repo or example of the code that can be seen?

Comment: I can give you the link for the site. But the project is still under development.

Comment: What should i post as an example?

Comment: No you don't need to give links to the live site, but more information about the image error would be useful. As said a couple comments ago, when the site was working (but without images) there would be information in your web browser console

Comment: And as a said there is no error, just a warming to delet all aces SDK-s

Comment: Please add image of `Application` tab in Developer Tools of chrome.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand you :((

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have deployed the wrong folder. Check your firebase.json and make sure your "hosting" > "public" is set to "build". Firebase init defaults to deploying the index folder, but npm run build by default creates a build folder for deployment.

Comment: Thank you, but I've solved the issue :) I upvoted tho.

Answer (score 1):

Add rewrite rule to **firebase.json** *(order is important)*

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/static/**",
        "destination": "/static/**"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```